# Avoiding duplicate entries in bash_history using ignoreboth:erasedups not working

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, iterm

I'm on Catalina using iterm but I know I've been facing this issue for years. I won't be surprised if this is related to [Why is .bash_history periodically wiped?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354746/why-is-bash-history-periodically-wiped) which answer explained why my bash history was behaving the way it is. This issue, however, still needs answers.

My `.bashrc` has all this related to history including `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups`:

```
   HISTFILESIZE=10000
   HISTSIZE=10000
   HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
   export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
   shopt -s histappend
```

Yet I see dups, see the latest sample:

```
 4637  30/09/22 11:31:53 git checkout master
 4638  30/09/22 11:33:51 git checkout misc15_db-change
 4639  30/09/22 11:33:54 git stash pop
 4640  30/09/22 11:34:04 git add -u
 4641  30/09/22 11:34:10 git diff --staged
 4642  30/09/22 11:31:53 git checkout master
 4643  30/09/22 11:33:51 git checkout misc15_db-change
 4644  30/09/22 11:33:54 git stash pop
 4645  30/09/22 11:34:04 git add -u
 4646  30/09/22 11:37:01 git diff --staged
```

What's interesting to see here is most of these dups are of the same timestamp with the exception of the last `git diff --staged` entry, which still shouldn't be there.

Comment: I think this is expected behaviour in bash. Posting this here for future reference. I don't have enough information to give a conclusive answer yet. [From this answer and even its question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265649/232271) at unix.se, "Note that ignoredups won't help with erasing **non-sequential duplicates** from an existing .bash_history."

Answer (score 1):

### Non-sequential duplicates are expected behaviour

This is expected behaviour as I found out some time back. `ignoreboth:erasedups` just doesn't erase non-sequential duplicates. See [How can I remove duplicates in my .bash_history, preserving order?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48713/) at Unix.SE.

They only erase *sequential* duplicates - so in this line of commands:

```
4639  30/09/22 11:33:54 git stash pop
4642  30/09/22 11:31:53 git checkout master
4644  30/09/22 11:33:54 git stash pop
```

`git stash pop` will be recorded twice. But if my line of commands were like this:

```
4642  30/09/22 11:31:53 git checkout master
4639  30/09/22 11:33:54 git stash pop
4644  30/09/22 11:33:54 git stash pop
```

`git stash pop` won't be recorded twice as we wanted.

### Copies of commands, not duplicates, are due to macOS's handling of `bash_history`

This is explained in [jksoegaard's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354757/) for [Why is .bash_history periodically wiped?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354746/why-is-bash-history-periodically-wiped)

Relevant excerpt from it:

> ...If you close down multiple bash sessions at once (for example closing down a terminal window with multiple tabs), you might lose part of or the whole history.

> ...Basically how it works is that your current history is read, the file is deleted/moved away, and a new file is created, where all the history lines are written to. If this process is running multiple times at the same time, you might see that one process removes the old history, the other process read an empty history, then the first process writes out the whole history again...

I have lost history like this. To remedy that, as per [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/460978/) to that same question:

> ... I close a window (say window1) and notice my history wiped in my new window (window3) via checking the history record count via `history | less` or anything similar. I notice that my old history still persists in window2 when I compare it. So I make it write my entire history again by running `history -w` in window2. Then I refresh history in window3 via `history -r` and this gets my old history back over there.

The potential side effect that can happen as seen in my own history's excerpt is that it can cause exact copies of commands to be in the history rather than just duplicates.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for contributing.  It's best to summarize answers here and link back to the supporting info (even if on another SE site) with the goal being that the answer can stand on it's own.  Though unlikely in this case, answers can get deleted making the info here inaccessible.  Consider an [edit] with the pertinent details to this post.

Comment: @Allan Thank you for your welcome and feedback. I've expanded my answer to stand on its own.

Comment: Nice edit!  Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: @Allan Thanks a lot. And thank you for your work here patrolling new answers and all. :)